# In Android, how can i allow the user to choose a color between 4?

Tags: android, controls, radio-button, widget

I'm making an Android App, and i need to put a control that let user choose between 4 different colors. I want to do this with something like radio buttons: the problem is that radiobuttons are round...

is there a way to set them looks like square/rect buttons, and assign a color to their inside rect area ?

If not, how can i achieve that choose for the user ?

I need this because i'm making a Todo/Task android application, and i need the user to choose the priority of a task, between for priority level that are rapresented with a color. So i think to do that by showing 4 buttons, each with a different color associated, and a text inside ("0", "1", "2", "3")

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> is there a way to set them looks like
>   square/rect buttons, and assign a
>   color to their inside rect area ?

Step #1: Copy `$ANDROID_HOME/platforms/$API/data/res/drawable/btn_radio.xml` to your project, where `$ANDROID_HOME` is where you have installed the Android SDK and `$API` is some Android platform (e.g., android-2.1)

Step #2: Copy `$ANDROID_HOME/platforms/$API/data/res/drawable-hdpi/btn_radio*` to your project

Step #3: Copy `$ANDROID_HOME/platforms/$API/data/res/drawable-mdpi/btn_radio*` to your project

Step #4: Modify those PNG files from steps #2 and #3 to suit your needs